# No conversion from 'T' to 'const char*' while using std::is_same<T,const char*>::value

Tags: c++

I have a class that uses operator<< chains to output stuff to both console and a file at the same time. I need to flush it whenever a line is broken, which happens with redefined endl (replaced with \n). This code doesn't work and spits out a lot of errors (no conversion from T to const char*). What is wrong?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


 /*class declaration*/

template <typename T>
inline Logger & Logger::operator<<(const T &a)
{
    if (debug::enabled)
    {
        std::cout << a;
        file << a;
        if (this->previousLineBroken)
        {
            std::cout << std::flush;
            file << std::flush;
            this->previousLineBroken = false;
        }
        if (std::is_same<T, const char*>::value) { 
            this->previousLineBroken = (a == debug::endl); 
        }
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Removing const from (const T &a) just makes things worse with more errors.

**UPD:** previousLineBroken is bool and debug::endl is const char* = "\n".

```
 //debug.h 
    #pragma once
    #define logger *logPtr
    #include "Classes.h"
    #include "logger.h"
    namespace debug
    {
        static const char* endl = "\n";
        static const bool enabled = true;
    }
    using debug::endl;
```

Comment: what are the types of `previousLineBroken` and `debug::endl`?

Comment: @static_cats bool and const char*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statement is not a **compile-time** branch, therefore the compiler will try to compile

```
this->previousLineBroken = (a == debug::endl);
```

for any `T`, even if

```
std::is_same<T, const char*>::value
```

is `false`. This *might* be the cause of your errors. You should add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

---

In C++17, you can make the `if` a compile-time branch by using `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr(std::is_same<T, const char*>::value) { 
    this->previousLineBroken = (a == debug::endl); 
}
```

---

In C++11, you can use an additional helper function and *overloading* instead:

```
template <typename T>
void setPreviousLineBroken(std::true_type, T a)
{
    this->previousLineBroken = (a == debug::endl); 
}

template <typename T>
void setPreviousLineBroken(std::false_type, T) { /* do nothing */ }
```

Your code will the look like:

```
template <typename T>
inline Logger & Logger::operator<<(const T &a)
{
    if (debug::enabled)
    {
        std::cout << a;
        file << a;
        if (this->previousLineBroken)
        {
            std::cout << std::flush;
            file << std::flush;
            this->previousLineBroken = false;
        }
        setPreviousLineBroken(std::is_same<T, const char*>{});
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: no way to to it in C++14 except making a dedicated function for const char*?

Comment: @AdmiralMyxtaR: you can implement your own `static_if`. I gave [a talk about this at CppCon 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k)